# Использованиеи dma_alloc_coherent

Tags: linux, c, драйвер, kernel

Правильно ли я понимаю, что если я выполнил три действия:

1. Вызвал *dma_alloc_coherent(...)*
2. Передал полученный физический адрес в устройство
3. Разрешил работу по DMA

то использовать *memcpy_fromio(...)* мне не нужно, в силу того, что этот блок памяти объявлен как **coherent** ?

Comment: Причём тут одно (DMA coherency) к другому (вызовы `memcpy_*io()`)? Это ортогональные вещи и никак не связаны между собой. Всё зависит от конкретной железки и как её необходимо программировать. В ядре можно найти не один драйвер, где будут использованы оба вызова, или ни одного, или один из них. О чём это скажет?

Comment: Да, и термины «физический адрес [памяти]» и  «память» у вас неправильно применены. Вы разберитесь для начала про существующие **адресные пространства**, и как указанные вызовы с ними связаны.